# How i can call JavaScript function from asp.net server side if script in user control

Tags: asp.net

I have a ASP.NET page with 1 user controls registered.

i have one server control

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="vidoUpdatebtn" OnClick="vidoUpdatebtn_Click" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

in .cs i handle

```
 protected void vidoUpdatebtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //do something
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "doSomeThing()", true);

    }
```

in user control i have function doSomeThing()

```
 function doSomeThing() {
         alert("TestReady");
     }
```

when i click on LinckButon registred function dosen't  work

Comment: 1st thing's 1st: RegisterStartupScript is a means of making javascript code appear in your page without actually writing it yourself everytime. You should write whatever javascript function you have instead of the "doSomeThing" identifier you wrote (that is the actual javascript code). Secondly: you shouldn't register the startup script when the user clicks the button (that is way to late). And last: registering the script is not enough. You must bind the OnClientClick attribute of the <asp:LinkButton> tag to the javascript function's name like so: "FunctionName()". Look at my answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write this in PageLoad (the only modifications from what you were writing are the moment in time of the registration -- PageLoad not Click, Click is too late and the face that you must write the actual implementation of the javascript function here):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", 
@"function doSomeThing() {
    alert(""TestReady"");
}"
        , true);
    }
```

and this in the asp:LinkButton tag (you must specify the OnClientClick attribute):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="vidoUpdatebtn" runat="server" OnClick="vidoUpdatebtn_Click" OnClientClick="doSomeThing()" >LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

And it should work.

Comment: thanks man this method helped me  but I changed it a little  
its work  even if i write ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "myscript", "fileUploadClick()" , true); because function doSomeThing() 
already exist in my user control

Comment: might I add that you can completely forget about the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript in that case. Try it and you'll see what I mean : if you already have the fileUploadClick function in your javascript, in your page, all you need to do is assign it's OnClientClick attribute accordingly. One way to try and discover if I'm right or wrong is modifying the RegisterStartupScript to: _ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "**blahblahblah**", "**andsomemoreblah**" , true);_ (literally) or even by commenting it entirely

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this way:

Add Script manager on your aspx page

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

Codebehind:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(),"myscript", "doSomeThing()",true);
```

Comment: What do you mean by it didn't help what is the error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

If you want client side code to run on the button click, you could use the OnClickClick property instead of the OnClick event. That'll also avoid the need for a postback and will give immediate feedback to the user.

e.g.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="vidoUpdatebtn" OnClientClick="alert('TestReady'); return false;" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```